# How to prove that $m(f\geq a)\leq \frac 1{a^n}\int f^n$?

Tags: measure-theory

Let $f:[0,1]\to\mathbf R_+$ be a measurable function and $a> 0$ such that $m(f\geq a)>0$.

I know that Markov's inequality states that $m(f\geq a)\leq\frac1a\int f$

How can it be deduced that $m(f\geq a)\leq \frac 1{a^n}\int f^n$?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

Apply Markov's inequality (which you already mentioned) to $f^n$ and $a^n$ instead of $f$ and $a$.

Comment: Oh yeah $x\mapsto x^{1/n}$ is increasing so $f\geq a\iff f^n\geq a^n$, thank you